# node.js' express middleware does not return error on nodester

Tags: node.js, express

My node app uses the express framework. I developed a middleware to check parameters but when an error is sent by the middleware it is not sent back in the response.
I only have this problem on nodester, on localhost it works as expected.

Here is an example of the controller action:

```
/*
 * Create a new user
 *
 */
app.post('/user/create', md.checkParams(["nickname", "email", "password"]), function(req, res){
  var email    = req.query.email;
  var nickname = req.query.nickname;
  var password = req.query.password;
  jsonObj = { "nickname" : nickname, "email" : email, "password" : password };

  // Save user in DB
  db.hmset("user:" +nickname, jsonObj, function(err1){
    if(!err1) {
      db.sadd("users","user:" + nickname, function(err2){
        if(err2){
          jsonObj = {"error" : "database error", "message" : "error adding object to set" };
        }
        h.respond(res, jsonObj);
      });
    } else {
      jsonObj = {"error" : "database error", "message" : "error creating hash for object" };
      h.respond(res, jsonObj);
    }
  });
});
```

The checkParams middleware is:

```
function checkParams(arr){
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Make sure each param listed in arr is present in req.query
    var missing_params = [];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(! eval("req.query." + arr[i])){
        missing_params.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    if(missing_params.length == 0){
      next();
    } else {
      next(JSON.stringify({ "error" : "query error", "message" : "Parameter(s) missing: " + missing_params.join(",") }));
    } 
  }
}
```

For instance, if I use a

```
curl -XPOST 'http://HOST/users/create'
```

on localhost I get:

{"error":"query error","message":"Parameter(s) missing: nickname,email,password"}

on NODESTER I only got:

```
Internal Server Error
```

({"error":"query error","message":"Parameter(s) missing: nickname,email,password"} appears in the app log but not in the response)

Any idea what could be wrong ?

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround by issuing the following in the middleware when an error is supposed to be thrown:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
res.write("my error message");
res.end();
```

instead of

```
next("my error message);
```

it's working this way even if I'm not 100% sure this is best solution.

Comment: The only "better" solution is to call `next("error", details)` and adding your own error handling middleware that writes details to the response. Getting this to play nicely with other middleware might be tricky. I think writing directly to the response gives you the most control and also removes edge cases.

Comment: @Raynos you'r right, that is good stuff. Could you change your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your express [configuration settings](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration).

by default under "development" the server returns error details whereas under "deployment" it hides them.

**Update**

With regards to your proposed solution. I would recommend you call next with multiple non standard parameters i.e.

`next("error", data)`

And then have a global middleware in connect that acts as a global error handling mechanism where you write error data to the response in your own personal manner.

You may have some edge cases where the middlewares behave strangely. You'll have to look into how `next` works in detail.

Comment: @Raynos, hmmm I only use "app = require('express').createServer();", no configuration defined. Cheers, I'll check in this direction.

Comment: @Raynos, I manage to get the "Internal Server Error" in local if I use the "app.use(express.errorHandler());". Still not able to disabled it in production.

Comment: @Luc don't use any errorHandler. Remove the `app.use` line. If you want a useful error message you can use `app.user(express.errorHandler({dumbExceptions: true}))`

Comment: @Raynos I did not use errorHandling at first place. Can it be activated by default in production ? how can I disable it ?

Comment: @Luc sound likes its tied to the next mechanism. youll have to read the middleware source or look at the connect documentation.